# Generate a collection of changed lines between two revisions of a file using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, comparison

I am writing an eclipse plugin which needs to be able to determine which lines of a file have changed compared to a different version of the same file.

Is there an existing class or library which I can use for this task?

The closest I have found is org.eclipse.compare.internal.merge.DocumentMerger. This can be used to find the information I need but is in an internal package so is not suitable for me to use. I could copy/paste the source of this class and adapt it to my requirements. However, I am hoping there is an existing library to handle textual comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For textual comparisons, try the [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library. (I don't know whether Eclipse already has something similar built-in.)